# NextJS Project CSS Styles are Changed after Deployment in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am currently working on a NextJS Project that has an  component. On my local environment everything works fine, when the viewport width changes the iFrame reacts changing the styles for the rendered page inside it. After deployment on Vercel Rendering the same component doesn't work. Styles are not causing any sort of reaction on the component rendered inside the iFrame, not even media queries. Any idea on why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue before and it's because the deployment environment on production, just install **cross-env** package and change the build script in your **package.json** file like this :

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NEXT_PUBLIC_FRAMEWORK=next NODE_ENV=development node server.js",
    "build-next": "cross-env NEXT_PUBLIC_FRAMEWORK=next next build",
    "build": "yarn build-next",
    "start": "node server.js -p 80",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging yarn build",
    "start-next": "cross-env NEXT_PUBLIC_FRAMEWORK=next NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
```

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks for your input

Comment: do you have MUI in your project ? then show me pls _document code